# Branching points(OpenCV,C++)

Tags: image, opencv, image-segmentation

I want to identify the branching points of the lightning in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXujf.jpg

What I did first was threshold the image such that I get the lighning part
of the image and discard the backround. This is the result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYNTi.jpg

I used the threshold function in openCV and the resulting image is pretty much bad
as the quality is lost, the branches are no longer visible.

Ok, basically I have 2 problems:

1. How can i properly segment the image such that the lightning part of the image is properly captured.
2. How can I then, identify the branching points? For every branch point i want to
   draw a red circle over it.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: `cvAdaptiveThreshold` should work better than normal threshold in this case.

Comment: Thanks Banthar, but how is it different to the normal thresholding?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lTRC5.jpg It will better separate lightnings from sky, jpeg artifacts will be more visible though.

Comment: Superb Banthar, step into the right direction, thumbs up bigtime (",)

Comment: Now if I perform morphological operation on the picture, like erode it, will it remove the small black dots in the image?

Comment: It should. You can also try to blur it before thresholding or tune threshold parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**Segmentation / thresholding:**
I would give [this](http://melodi.ee.washington.edu/~jegelka/cc/coopcode2.html) a try.
They also had a NIPS2012 workshop (DISCML) paper on image segmentation that seems to handle quite elegantly thin elongated objects (like the lightnings in the picture).

**Branching points:**
Once you have a good mask you can use [morphological operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) to extract the branching points (Matlab code):

```
 bw = myGoodSegmentation( img ); % replace with whatever segmentation/thresholding that works best for you.
 tbw = bwmorph( bw, 'skel', inf );
 [y x] = find( bwmorph( tbw, 'branchpoints' ) ); % get x,y coordinates of branch points
```